# MySQL - SELECT Returns Vague Null Value

Tags: mysql, select, case

Please take a look at the query :

```
 SELECT Id
   FROM TableA
  WHERE ColumnA = 'foo'
  ORDER BY Id DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Basically, I want the query to fetch the latest entry on **TableA** ( Column **Id** is **AI** ) with the stated condition **ColumnA = 'foo'**.

The query will run smoothly and returns what I need. If there is no table entry that will match the condition **ColumnA = 'foo'**, the result is **null**.

With that being said, I added a **CASE** to return **1** instead. **ELSE**, return the **Id**. Below is the new query:

```
 SELECT CASE
            WHEN Id IS NULL
            THEN 1
            ELSE Id
        END
   FROM TableA
  WHERE ColumnA = 'foo'
  ORDER BY Id DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Using the given query, if the condition is false, there wont be any result. It's blank. Not even NULL.

The question is, why is that? In my perspective, the result should be **1**.

Here's a Fiddle link for your testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8e3af/3

**Note**:
This will work if I use **MAX** instead of limiting the result to 1. I'm just wondering why this solution will not work.

Comment: Result should not be null using the first query either if there are no matching rows. It should be an empty result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID is never null because no row is returned, and the CASE WHEN will never be executed. A workaround would be like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ID), 1) AS ID
FROM (
  SELECT  ID
  FROM TableA
  WHERE ColumnA = 'G'
  ORDER BY Id DESC
  LIMIT 1
) s
```

(an aggregated query will always return a row, with MAX(ID) if an ID is returned or with null if no rows are returned from the subquery)

Comment: I see. This is why CASE
            WHEN MAX(Id) IS NULL
            THEN 1
            ELSE MAX(Id)
        END returns 1 whenever the condition returns false

Answer (score 2):

you can try this it may be useful for you

```
SELECT IFNULL(Id,1) as ID
FROM TableA
WHERE ColumnA = 'foo'
ORDER BY Id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish. I'm looking for why the given query doesn't return anything not the work around. Thanks for your time anyway. +1